# Newton Rapshon with trigonometric function

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Calculate the root of $x+cos(x)=0$ with Newton-Raphson method.

Could anyone help me on how to apply Newton-Raphson on this equation that includes trigonomtric functions?

Answer (score 3):

The function you want the root of is
$$f(x)=x+\cos x$$
The derivative of that function is
$$f'(x)=1-\sin x$$
Since Newton's method uses the iteration $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$, we substitute the expressions for function and derivative:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n+\cos x_n}{1-\sin x_n}$$
With that done we need a starting value $x_0$ where $f(x_0)$ is close to zero; here we can take $x_0=-0.5$ (this value being found by looking at the graph). Iterate:
$$x_1=-0.7552224171\dots$$
$$x_2=-0.7391416661\dots$$
$$x_3=-0.7390851339\dots$$
$$x_4=-0.7390851332\dots$$
$$x_5=-0.7390851332\dots$$
Our value of *x* is now not changing (at least within our working precision), so we can stop and conclude that the root of $x+\cos x$ is $-0.7390851332\dots$

Comment: how we choose that starting value?

Comment: By looking at the graph of your function, or by trial and error. Newton's method is robust enough to work with a fairly wide range of starting values, but it works better the closer we are to the root.

Comment: if i take $1$ will i do more steps?

Comment: It will take more steps for this function of yours, but it will get to the root eventually. I must warn you, however, that Newton's method will not converge to a root for some other functions _if given a bad starting value_.

Comment: and what about if i take $0.5$ instead of negative

Comment: It still converges!